# Rails 6.1: undefined method `deduplicate'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my Rails 5.1 code I created a new column dynamically using:

```
cast_type = ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new

column = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new('foo_name', true, cast_type)
```

but after I upgraded to Rails 6.1 I'm getting the error message:

```
 undefined method `deduplicate' for #<ActiveModel::Type::Boolean:
```

Indeed, there is no such method since:

```
ActiveModel::Type::Boolean.new.respond_to?('deduplicate')
```

returns "false".

I see in the Rails' file:

```
 activerecord-6.1.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/column.rb
```

that the **deduplicate** method is called around line 93:

```
 sql_type_metadata.deduplicate
```

But I don't know how to create the "sql_type_metadata" object. I see the Rails' file:

```
activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sql_type_metadata.rb
```

and that file indeed includes the "Deduplicable" module. But I don't know how to create one object from that file and then pass it to:

```
 ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new('foo_name', true, sql_type_metadata)
```

I guess I need something like:

```
 ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SqlTypeMetadata.new(
        sql_type: sql_type,
        type: cast_type.type,
        limit: cast_type.limit,
        precision: cast_type.precision,
        scale: cast_type.scale,
      )
```

the "cast_type" part comes from the "ActiveModel::Type" derived object, but what "sql_type" means?

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ColumnDefinition/sql_type

Answer (score 0):

```
 cast_type = ActiveRecord::Type.const_get('Boolean').new

 sql_type_metadata = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SqlTypeMetadata.new(
    sql_type: cast_type.type.to_s,
    type: cast_type.type,
    limit: cast_type.limit,
    precision: cast_type.precision,
    scale: cast_type.scale)

  column = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Column.new('foo', sql_type_metadata)
```